# python versions (conda -forge)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I am using 18.04 Ubuntu with Anaconda.Recently i have trying to install OpenCV through conda-forge channel in the base environment. I did not install purposely any Python version and did not use any pip command either in base environment. Now, in the base environment, if execute just python, i get the same python version as system version and if execute python3 , i get the version installed by conda-forge. Please refer the screen shot. [Python_on_Conda_base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWTOl.png)

I would like to know what is difference between python and python3 command?.What is should i keep in mind? basically i prefer the version 3.7.5 Python
.So, only the Python3 has uses different version. So, question what i should take note when i using `python3 some_script.py`? what is pros and cons of  having this 2 version?

So far,i did not face any issues, but removed the conda-forge channel from Anaconda to avoid any conflicts. Any thoughts?
After posting this question, i have noticed `python --version`  command gives `Python 3.7.5`  on Conda  base environment and Ubuntu terminal  (outside Conda)

Comment: `which python` will tell you the location of the executable. Also, please don't post textual information as images. Instead, edit your question and include the commands and outputs directly.

Comment: okay. Noted. in Conda base environment `which python and which python3`  gives `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3` seems it uses same version. Right?  Deactivate Conda base, on bash Terminal i am getting ` /usr/bin/python` for where is python and `/usr/bin/python3` for where is python3.

Comment: They should give different results if their versions differ. Also, you should explicitly install Python into your environment. It will then use the python binary from that environment instead of the one that comes with Conda.

Comment: i have installed Python during, Anaconda conda (Graphical installation). Almost all the time, i was working with base environment. I just noticed - python --version command gives Python 3.7.5 on Conda base environment and Ubuntu terminal (outside Conda). (edited the question accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have set an alias for `python` to point to the python3 binary.

Check this by typing `type python`, which will probably give you

```
python is aliased to ...
```

The crux here is that an alias will not be detected by `which` and as you revealed in the comments your `which python` returns the correct python version from your conda base environment, which makes an alias the most likely explanation, as `PATH` issues can be ruled out.

If above command does indeed reveal an alias, then check you `.bashrc` or similar file that you might have modified for a line `alias python=...`. Delete it, restart your terminal and everything should work normally

Comment: Since you accepted the answer I assume you also got it fixed by deleting the alias?

Comment: On Conda environment `type python`  python is aliased to `python3.7`. seems normal. 'type python3` gives `python3 is hashed (/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3)`.On anaconda3/bin , i have 'python -> python3.8'  and 'python3 -> python3.8'. What this mean?  would like to point to `python3 -> python3.7`  (executable present in  anaconda\bin folder)

Comment: `On Conda environment type python python is aliased to python3.7. seems normal` <- no it is not. conda does not create aliases. Delete that alias from your .bashrc or whereever you have created it

Comment: You have python3.8 installed in your conda base env, and python3.7 is installed globally under /usr/bin. Now you have an alias `python->python3.7`. Because of that typing `python` will always point to your systems `python3.7` installation, which is not from conda. When you type `python38`, then the executable in your anaconda folder is found, because it is the only match for python38

Comment: .bashrc does not mention python environment but it has `conda.sh' on  conda initialize part. will explore conda.sh part. Thanks.